# Custom ttf font with python plotly on headless linux machine

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I want to create plotly diagrams in different languages and fonts and save them as svgs in python.
As the application will be installed on docker systems which does not have GNOME and user would select the language and font for their diagrams.

As per the plotly documentation, it supports system fonts that are installed to be used for change the font by updating `font` property in layout.
For example: `font=dict(family="Franklin Gothic", size=18)`

My requirement is that as I have linux system without GUI, I cannot install ttf fonts. And the python script should run on Windows, Mac and Linux (for servers and docker systems without GNOME) to generate plotly diagrams and save SVG with the custom font local ttf files which are stored in the local directory.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=t, y=np.sin(t),
    name='sin',
    mode='markers',
    marker_color='rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)'
))

fig.update_layout(title='Styled Scatter',
                  yaxis_zeroline=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)

fig.show()
```

I want something like below to work:
`fig.update_layout(font=dict(family="/usr/fonts/Noto Sans.ttf", size=18)`

Currently, this is not considered by plotly and it seems to be using default font that are installed with plotly installation.

It shall be of great help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Just give url of font directly like this:

```
fig.update_layout(font="https://github.com/matomo-org/travis-scripts/raw/master/fonts/Arial.ttf")
```

Comment: This does not work in Plotly 5.18.0. It fails with `ValueError: Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'font' property of layout"`.

If I change the `font=` to `font_family=`, it doesn't error, but it also doesn't use the specified font. The docs do not mention the ability to load a font from a URL; they say "the web browser will only be able to apply a font if it is available on the system which it operates."