# How to specify a local TTF file as a layout font in Plotly (Python) on PaaS?

Tags: python, fonts, plotly

I have a **TrueType** font file that I want to use as the layout font in a chart created with **Plotly** (*Python*). However, I can't set the font manually in the system because the chart is generated on **PaaS**.

I have tried using `fig.update_layout(font_family=f"assets/{font_name}.ttf")`, but it doesn't work and just changes the font to the standard one (*Open Sans*). I have also attempted to install the font using the link (like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73318757/11937776)), but that doesn't work either.

---

Here's a code snippet for reference:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "data": data})

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y="data")
fig.update_layout(font_family=f"assets/{font_name}.ttf") # This line works incorrect

fig.write_image(f"images/{file_name}.png")
```

---

**How can I specify a local font file to use in my chart, or is there another way to set the font using code?**

Comment: which kind of PaaS? Maybe you can create your own docker image to upload on PaaS that has installed the required font

Comment: @mattiatantardini Railway

Comment: I don't know the service, but with a quick search I found that it supports building the app from Dockerfile: https://docs.railway.app/deploy/dockerfiles. This may be a workaround for you, needed to manually install the font

Answer (score -1):

You can try providing absolute path to the .ttf file like this:

`fig.update_layout(font_family=f"{os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())}/assets/Font-Regular.ttf")`

Comment: This has the same effect as before. The default font is still set.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I also tried building a URI like "file:///path/to/file.ttf". That doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

The font you set in your code is displayed only if it’s installed on your computer. So, to use a font, first, you need to install it on your computer.
if you don't know how, you can follow this [link](https://www.lifewire.com/installing-truetype-or-opentype-fonts-in-windows-1074134).
I ran this code with sample data as shown below (note that I have already installed the font "Mistral"):

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2023-09-18", "2023-09-17", "2023-09-16", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-14", "2023-09-13", "2023-09-12", "2023-09-11", "2023-09-10"], 
                   "data": [10,20,30,-50,10,70,24,26,25]})

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y="data")

# Set the custom font
fig.update_layout(font_family="Mistral")

fig.write_image("test.png")
```

and [here is the outputted image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdfdv.png)

Comment: From the question: `However, I can't set the font manually in the system because the chart is generated on PaaS.`